# Overload on << like cout error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to create a class like **std::cout**, however, with colored output. The idea is to call colorstream, but when I overload the operator << gives error.

Codes below:

***main.cpp***

```
#include <colorstream/colorstream.hpp>

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
cpk::colorstream test;
test << "Hello World";

return 0;
}
```

***colorstream/colorstream.hpp***

```
#include <string>

#ifndef CPK_COLORSTREAM_HPP
#define CPK_COLORSTREAM_HPP

namespace cpk
{
    class colorstream
    {
    public:
        colorstream ( ) { };
        colorstream operator<<( std::string n );
    };
}

#endif // #ifndef CPK_COLORSTREAM_HPP
```

***colorstream/colorstream.cpp***

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

/**
 * CPK Color Stream Header
 */
#include <colorstream/colorstream.hpp>

cpk::colorstream::colorstream operator<<( std::string n )
{
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

This is the first time I'm trying to overload operators in, so please help me and if I can explain my mistake.

Thank you, Bruno Alano

@edit
The error:

```
CMakeFiles/cpk.dir/source/cpk.cpp.o: In function `main':
cpk.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `cpk::colorstream::operator<<(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: ** [cpk] Erro 1
make[1]: ** [CMakeFiles/cpk.dir/all] Erro 2
make: ** [all] Erro 2
```

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get a compiler error? It compiles  but doesn't produce the expected output?

Comment: Can you please also include the error so we don't have to guess?

Comment: `std::cout` is not a class, it is a global `std::iostream` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the error is that you're definition of the operator is garbled. It should be

cpk::colorstream cpk::colorstream::operator<< (std::string n)

That said, I strong recommend **not** to pursue this approach further! To create custom streams you want to derive from `std::streambuf` and override the relevant operations there (e.g. `overflow()` and, possibly, `xsputn()` for output streams).

Actually, if you want to change color e.g. using [ANSI Escape Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) you can just create suitable color manipulators and use them with an `std::ostream`:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace color
{
    std::ostream& red(std::ostream& out) {
        return out << "\x1b[31m";
    }
    std::ostream& reset(std::ostream& out) {
        return out << "\x1b[0m";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello " << color::red << "world" << color::reset << "\n";
}
```

On non-UNIX platforms some other mechanism might be necessary, though...

Answer (score 2):

When defining a member operator, what you need to qualify with the class name is the operator name, not the return type.

```
namespace cpk {
    colorstream colorstream::operator<<( std::string n )
    {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now, to allow chaining calls to `<<` like you can do with `std::cout` you need to actually return a value from your operator!

```
namespace cpk {
    colorstream colorstream::operator<<( std::string n )
    {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

However, this will return a copy of the stream because it returns by value. That's probably not desirable, so you might be better with returning by reference:

```
    colorstream& colorstream::operator<<( std::string n )
    {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: To deflect your next question, you probably will get a warning because you are reaching the end of a non-void function without returning. You might want to return a `colorstream &` from your function (and add `return *this` at the end

Answer (score 0):

I need more information on what you are trying to accomplish and what are the errors that are coming up.

I made an assumption with the code provided below that you wanted to output the color to standard out.
I feel that I am completely wrong with this assumption, however here is the code...

**main.cpp**

```
#include <colorstream/colorstream.hpp>

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    cpk::colorstream test;
    test.SetColor("RED");
    std::cout << test << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**colorstream/colorstream.hpp** should be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifndef CPK_COLORSTREAM_HPP
#define CPK_COLORSTREAM_HPP

namespace cpk
{
    class colorstream
    {
    public:
        std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const cpk::colorstream& cs);
        void SetColor(const std::string &color){m_Color = color;}
    private:
        std::string m_Color;
    };
}

#endif // #ifndef CPK_COLORSTREAM_HPP
```

**colorstream/colorstream.cpp** should be:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

/**
 * CPK Color Stream Header
 */
#include <colorstream/colorstream.hpp>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const cpk::colorstream& cs) 
{
    stream << cs.m_Color; 
    return stream;
}
```